# Layout Messes up with Different Simulators

Tags: xml, html, blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I'm having some trouble with the Ripple Emulator and the Blackberry Simulator. The ripple emulator, seen as the larger picture below, shows what the application is designed to look like (I have been developing on the Ripple emulator so far). I next tried packaging and launching the application on the blackberry simulator and the app breaks down in layout as can be seen below. My question is why is this occuring, and is there a way to fix this? Do I have to place something in my config.xml file to change this?

[image]

Config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
        version="2.0"
        rim:header="RIM-Widget: rim/widget">

  <author>our company</author>
  <rim:navigation mode="focus" />
  <name>Application1</name>

  <description>
    This application is having trouble displaying itself
  </description>
  <rim:orientation mode="portrait"/>
  <rim:loadingScreen backgroundImage="images\background.png"
                     foregroundImage="images\foreground.png"
                     onLocalPageLoad="true">
        <rim:transitionEffect type="zoomIn" />
  </rim:loadingScreen>

  <icon src="icons/icon.png"/>
  <icon src="icons/icon.png" rim:hover="true"/>
        <rim:cache maxCacheSizeTotal="2048" maxCacheSizeItem ="256" />
  <content src="index.htm" >
  </content>

  <feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog"/>
  <feature id="webworks.notification" />

  <rim:connection timeout="25000">
    <id>TCP_WIFI</id>
    <id>MDS</id>
    <id>BIS-B</id>
    <id>TCP_CELLULAR</id>
    <id>WAP2</id>
    <id>WAP</id>
  </rim:connection>
</widget>
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because of different resolutions of blackberry simulators, like blackberry strom 9550 have screen resolution of 340x480 and blackberry bold 9700 have screen resolution of 480x340.

We can solve this layout problem only using coding. Use % ratio instead of using no of pixels value.

Comment: that's what I'm currently doing, don't understand why it's doing this